# How to merge dictionaries with many values in the same keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, nested

I have a small problem with creating my code. I am trying to merge two dictionaries in Python. Each of them has set of keys lets say:

```
a={person_id:xx, address_id: xx, name:xx}
b={address_id:xx, street:xx, postcode:xx, town:xx}
```

Each of them has many entries and by that I mean they look like:

```
a={person_id:1. address_id:20, name:john; person_id:2, address_id:200, 
   name: mary';... and 10000 more entries like that}

b={address_id:20... same situation like in a}
```

I would like to get:

```
merged_dic={person_id:xx, address_id {street:xx, postcode:xx, town:xx}, name:xx; person_id:xxx.. and so on}
```

I tried so many different things, update, defaultdict and many more and none of them worked. I don't want to overwrite things, I just want to create some sort of nested dict.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: *some sort* of nested dictionary?  That is rather vague.

Comment: sorry for that, what I meant is that I wanted to get all the 10k values listed in the form of merged_dic={person_id:xx, address_id {street:xx, postcode:xx, town:xx}, name:xx; person_id:xxx.. and so on}, I don't really know how to call it properly, still a beginner and trying to learn. Tbh whatever I am trying to do it does not show all the values properly, either overwrites it or shows just a limited number like the last value of dictionary a and not all of them.

Comment: Could you please post actual Python data structure literals (e.g. what does the semicolon in the dict?). Your `a` dict has duplicate keys and one can't c'n'p this code.

Comment: I dont understand your dictionary, you should explain it more.

Comment: Hi, yes there are multiple, duplicate keys (around a few thousand entries) but with different values in both dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

To merge the dict you might want to try the `dict.update()` method like:

#### Code:

```
def merge_my_dicts(a_dict, b_dict):
    # verify the addresses match
    assert b_dict['address_id'] == a_dict['address_id']

    # get a copy of the address dict and remove extra
    address = b_dict.copy()
    del address['address_id']

    # get a copy of the main dict, and update with the address
    new_dict = a_dict.copy()
    new_dict.update({'address_id': address})
    return new_dict
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = {'person_id': 'pid', 'address_id': 'aid', 'name': 'nm'}
b = {'address_id': 'aid', 'street': 'st', 'postcode': 'pc', 'town': 'tn'}
print(merge_my_dicts(a, b))
```

#### Results:

```
{
    'person_id': 'pid', 
    'address_id': {
        'street': 'st', 
        'postcode': 'pc', 
        'town': 'tn'},
    'name': 'nm'
}
```

Comment: It is a good option, thanks! But unfortunately, it only works if dicts do not have duplicate keys with different values and these ones have. I tried the update and it only shows the last entry and I want to get all of them.

Comment: @Vesh, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.